# What is the source of my 'Blacklist irretrievable' error?

Tags: error, control-panel

When I go to download the blacklist in a recent install of v2.5.3 - Build Date: 20120911 I get this…

> Error: New blacklist was irretrievable.
>
> Did not receive a '200 OK' response from remote server. (HTTP/1.1 301
>   Moved Permanently)

[image: screenshot]

I've raised a ticket with EllisLab about this with my new complimentary Silver plan. I'm guessing it's to do with the domain rerouting that's happened over the weekend.

Wonder if anyone here can offer suggestions quicker than EllisLab ;)

Comment: I'd suggest posting this as a [bug report](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/submit). There's not a lot that anyone outside of EllisLab can do.

Comment: Posted: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19038 (wishes EL bug comments were editable to fix errors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like in `/system/expressionengine/modules/blacklist/mcp.blacklist.php` on line 593 it's pinging: http://ping.expressionengine.com/index.php. Most likely an oversight on EL

Comment: this is definitely the problem. Either disable the blacklist or find what the correct ping address and edit the file siebird mentions.

Comment: Thanks Siebird for digging out the code source. I'd figured there would be an EL dependency here but it's interesting how much swifter the response is here than from EL!

Comment: I feel there is a sense of urgency for the community to post the correct answer to get their rep up! I definitely like this model!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't think you're going to get a solution here. The same thing (new domain routing issue) happened with the EE CP Accessory, and I assume this is in the same boat. I'm not sure if 'I can't answer your question' is a good enough answer for SE though!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are at their mercy on this I think. You can always uninstall the addon if it's causing problems.

Comment: Do you have any 'Urgent Support' tickets? :D

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'd say you'll have to remove it and wait for an update to that module or for them to reinstate that url.